# IWebBrowser2.ReadyState vs. IHtmlDocument2.readyState

Tags: internet-explorer, com, iwebbrowser2

I found that they sometimes don't correlate.
For instance IWebBrowser2.ReadyState can have READYSTATE_LOADING value while IHtmlDocument2.readyState gives 'completed'.
Is there anywhere documentation ?
I see this behavior when I open a website in a new tab using middle click.

[IWebBrowser::ReadyState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752066(v=vs.85).aspx)

[IHTMLDocument2::readyState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752602(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: You can have multiple document instances per browser instance

Comment: What do you mean multiple documents? Can you give a sample of html page with such behavior?

Comment: A browser is a browser, it can have windows, frames, etc... A page is a single document. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/497d9c38-02f5-4ac8-a928-a29213a7b90b/relationship-between-iwebbrowser2-ihtmlwindow-ihtmldocument?forum=ieextensiondevelopment